# Can flex connect to WCF?

Tags: apache-flex, wcf

I want to flex connect to a WCF with RTMP. is there an abillity to create RTMP custom binding in WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, from what I've read of the [RMTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), it would be possible to create a transport channel in WCF.

Note, a transport channel is what you really want to create, because that's going to handle the low-level transport of bytes over the wire.

The largest hurdle I see being overcome is handling the different channel ids in the protocol for a single session.  Depending on how exactly that is handled (if you are using RTMPT for example, the channel id might be in the header, so the same endpoint in WCF can work with that and perform the appropriate operation), it might require extensive, or not-so-extensive work with the transport channel.

I would suggest looking at the [Channel Model Overview in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729840.aspx) and then looking at [winterdom's blog entry on writing a WCF transport channel](http://winterdom.com/2007/02/writingawcftransportchannelpart1), as it walks you through creating a WCF transport channel, as well as has a treasure-trove of links to other resources useful in understanding how to create your own WCF transport channel.